# Is my R version corrupted because of mingw?

Tags: r

Few days ago, I installed c++ mingw compiler and removed it yesterday.

Even before using mingw compiler to dabble with eclipse ide, I had R Studio installed with the default CRAN version of R. After deleting mingw folder from my computer, I see this kind of wierd mingw name in the default text shown by the console window in R Studio.

Kind of annoying to me!! I dont want to deal with mingw and want that name to disappear completely...

This is not affecting the overall functionality...Not sure if it will affect int he future..... but wondering why the "mingw" text is showing up in the "Platform" information....

Is there a way to restore normalcy ?[annoying mingw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQKIA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news... you've already achieved normalcy!

```
R.version$platform
# [1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"
```

What you are seeing *is the canonical name of the platform under which R was compiled* according to the help entry... `?.Platform`

Comment: Well... It was not the default name that was present when I first started playing with R studio

Comment: So... Why is it showing up now....

Comment: OH... DAMN.... just realised that it is the default message.... Checked console message of windows based machines in Google images.... LOlled pretty hard.... Hahaha